# A dozen mac mini's vs dell rack server for parallel image processing

Tags: cluster, hpc

I need to do some large scale image processing in parallel.

I was thinking of running a dozen Mac Mini's in parallel to do the data processing.
I need to run Microsoft Windows on the machines so I can pull the data from the network using an Active X control, the only way the data is available (there are plenty of servers that I can pull the data from).

Is there a cheaper / more efficient way using rack servers by Dell or another company? 
The Mac Mini has got the three things I need for $800 :

1. Gigabit Ethernet
2. CUDA video card
3. 4 GB RAM  (+100 from base mac mini).

Is there any setup that is cheaper ?

Answer (score 1):

Rack server against: noise, heat and lack of anything more than a basic GPU.
Rack server for: centralising all of your resources (stuffing said server with RAM and CPUs) and getting it to do your heavy lifting, it makes computer management much easier.

I don't know what sort of image processing you require, but I'd be asking myself the following.

- Is your task easy to distribute (ala hadoop) across several boxes?
- Is it possible to do this on the intel Atom platform?  Less heat/power needed, and cheaper, and you don't have to kill a dozen Mac Os's
- Can one or two GPU/graphics card bear a lot of the grunt needed - if so look at gamer PCs?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would say that for a low-cost solution, that would probably be alright.  The problems that I see are:

- Typically server clusters use a stripped-down OS (think Linux or a
  BSD) with a bare-minimum of services
  / apps.  Neither MacOS or Windows fit
  this bill.
- You can probably get a better break on pricing going with another machine
  type.  Honestly, you can probably get
  a laptop from an office-supply or
  big-box retailer for a comparable (if
  not cheaper) price.  (...or NewEgg, or Amazon, or TigerDirect, or ...)  Finding gigabit
  network and 4GB of RAM should not be
  hard.  (While I love the Mac Mini, it doesn't sound like it gains you any real benefit in this case.)

Also, Mac Minis aren't Rack servers, even if you place them in a rack.  (Yes, you can purchase rack-mountable shelves, but that still doesn't make the Mini a rack-server...)  Rack-mount servers are a very specific chassis type.  They aren't cheap; typically a rack-mount server will be more expensive than a comparably-equipped Tower server.

**FURTHER**:

If possible, it may be worthwhile to have one Windows box dedicated to pulling in the images (via your activeX control), dumping them into a share which is then accessed by a *nix cluster for processing.  (Assuming that the downloading isn't the part that needs processing.)

Comment: I already have plenty of nix cluster hardware available for processing.  This is a preprocessing cluster.  I need all windows machines pulling down data from the network as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Helmer Cluster](http://helmer.sfe.se/) project? It is a low-cost cluster of machines used for image rendering. They even provide some stats/benchmarks at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this thread helpful which talks about suitability of mac mini for Hadoop Cluster http://groups.google.com/group/bigdatasg/browse_thread/thread/51ad3da711d333d3

Document also available at: http://www.scribd.com/doc/76827185/Mac-Mini-Hadoop-Cluster

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.